# Import 'watchdog.observers' could not be resolved (Python, Win10)

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, watchdog

Working with Python on Win10, I pip-installed watchdog into my venv, and it's listed when I do a 'pip list'.
I activate venv in VSCode Terminal.
Then I try:

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
```

- *Pylint* error message: 'unable to import watchdog.observers'
- *Pylance* error message: 'Import "watchdog.observers" could not be resolved'

Any idea?

**Solution:**

The problem was: there were spaces in the path to the *venv*, that seem to prevent installing watchdog. 'pip list' showed a watchdog in another directory, not from the venv.

Comment: ```Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'watchdog'
  File "D:\Backup_Script\backup.py", line 17, in <module>
    from watchdog.observers import Observer
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'watchdog'```

     I checked again: I am in my venv, and 'pip list' shows 'watchdog 3.0.0'

Comment: Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments! Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was: there were spaces in the path to the venv, that seem to prevent installing watchdog. 'pip list' showed a watchdog in another directory, not from the venv.

Answer (score 0):

Please choose the correct python interpreter.

Use shortcuts **"Ctrl+Shift+P"** and type **"Python: Select Interpreter"** to choose the venv environment.

Comment: This was not the solution, but it opened my exes to find the real problem (see solution in OP). Thanks!